# Request to Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I need to send a request to the server like this

```
[{
 "Case":"add",
 "Table":"user",
 "Field":["Email","Password"],
 "Value":["a","a"],
 "Duplicate":["Email"],
 "SecureEncrpt":"Password",
 "SecureDecrpt":"Password"
}]
```

and I'm using alamofire for the network process, and im using request structure like this

```
let loginparas = [
    "Case": "add",
    "Table":"user",
    "Field":["Email","Password"],
    "Value":[details,pass],
    "Duplicate":["Email"],
    "SecureEncrpt":"",
    "SecureDecrpt":""

] as AnyObject 

let parameters = loginparas as! Parameters
```

How can I get exactly like that format?

Comment: you can sent key value pare as parameters

Comment: your mentioned request packet is array of object not key value pare (Dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

```
let loginparas = [
       "Case": "add",
       "Table":"user",
       "Field":["Email","Password"],
       "Value":[details,pass],
       "Duplicate":["Email"],
       "SecureEncrpt":"",
       "SecureDecrpt":""

   ] as [String:Any]

   Alamofire.request( url , method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers ).responseJSON { response in

    if response.result.isSuccess {
        guard let json = response.result.value as? NSArray else { return }

        for j in json {
          let jsonValur = j as? [String:Any]
          let case = jsonValue["Case"] as? String
          ...
          ...
          ...
        }  

    }

   }
```

Comment: From [Documentations](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#making-requests): **"There are additional methods that allow you to make requests using Parameters dictionaries and ParameterEncoding types. This API is no longer recommended and will eventually be deprecated and removed from Alamofire."** It will be removed so how it will be done after that?